# Yii2 :: Move controllers, models and views to subfolders

Tags: php, yii2, structure

Have a structure:

```
modules/
-- office/
---- controllers/
-------- industryController.php
-------- industryAttrController.php
-------- userAdminController.php
-------- userAdminAttrController.php
---- modules/
-------- industry.php
-------- industryAttr.php
-------- userAdmin.php
-------- userAdminAttr.php
---- views/
-------- industry/
-------- industry-attr/
-------- userAdmin/
-------- userAdminAttr/
```

I want to change it to:

```
modules/
-- office/
---- controllers/
-------- industry/
------------ industryController.php
------------ industryAttrController.php
-------- user-admin/
------------ userAdminController.php
------------ userAdminAttrController.php
---- modules/
-------- industry/
------------ industry.php
------------ industryAttr.php
-------- user-admin/
------------ userAdmin.php
------------ userAdminAttr.php
---- views/
-------- industry/
------------ industry/
------------ industry-attr/
-------- userAdmin/
------------ userAdmin/
------------ userAdminAttr/
```

I try to move controllers in folders and I found in OfficeModule.php this code:

```
namespace app\modules\office;

/**
 * office module definition class
 */
class OfficeModule extends \yii\base\Module
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\office\controllers';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->layout = 'office';
    }
}
```

But I can set only one folder for controllers here. Can I add another paths or may it is impossible?

Also I want to move models and views in subfolders too.

I just started to learn Yii2, so please give me full answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is some sort of "convention" here. If you want to separate your logic on fronend / backend you should make them work like different modules. Your structure should look more like

```
backend
-assets
-config
-controllers
-models
-runtime
-views
-web
common
-config
-models
frontend
-assets
-config
-controllers
-models
-runtime
-views
-web
```

The main thing is that you should have components / controllers / models etc depending on the module not the path - so its path / all stuff not controller / path ...

In there you can put whatever folders you want, and just configure the namespaces correctly. Such a projects is the Yii advanced template:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

Look at it and you will probably understand the logic behind this separation. If you have more questions I will answer you in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, but I have start with basic yii2 and have create module for admin area

Comment: Another way to achieve what you want is to have a MAIN controller that is responsible only for calling needed controllers eg. You have a method in your MAIN controller answering for operation of certain controller. You call there the needed functionality from your "child" controller and do your logic. Those managing classes can be done for models / controllers / views everything but the whole idea behind it is wrong. So I again advice you to review the whole project and to look in perspective if in the future what you want won't be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Have read errors log and found solution:

```
1) Have change namespaces (controllers)
2) After that I had error that can't find view files, so I have move view/industry/ -> view/industry/industry
3) Have move models to subfolder
4) Have change all `use` in all files
```

But now I have a problem with path: site.local/office/industry/industry/index

I want to remove one industry from path. How can I do that?